# EPiServer 8. XForm doesn't send mail and doesn't redirect

Tags: xforms, episerver-8

As the title says, my problem is quite easy to describe. I have an Xform in EPiServer CMS 8 that does not send a mail after data is submittet and there is not even redirection to the chosen response page.

There is no extra coding in the page template and the form is quite simple, just a text field (no validation on it) and a button that is supposed to send data to DB and send a mail. The data is saved though, but nothing else happens.

The SMTP is working fine with the configuration in form (I have tested in another application). Also when I change to just "Save to Database", there's still no redirection to response page.

Does anyone have a clue? I don't get any error messages, nothing in log files, nothing at all. I have changed log configuration to show All messages.

/Kenia

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a javascript error, if you run it in chrome and have activated f12 and choosen console, do you see any errors there when submitting the form?